# Integration between vrapper (Eclipse) and nvim-qt

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt, vrapper

I use [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/), which is a great plugin, providing some vim emulation to Eclipse.

One of the features of Vrapper is that from anywhere you can type `:vim` and it will reopen the file you are currently editing into gvim. (This is quite useful when you want to use the full power of Vim from Eclipse.)

Users provide the path to a gvim executable to the plugin through a `_vrapperrc` file.

Currently, if I set the path as follows, it works (with gvim)

```
set gvimpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\gvim.exe"
```

However, I also use nvim-qt, and the following setup doesn't work:

```
set gvimpath="C:\Users\blah\Documents\tools\nvim\Neovim\bin\nvim-qt.exe"
```

I am on the last vrapper stable version.

It might be a vrapper bug, but I am posting hoping someone has a similar setup and solved the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is the option `gvimargs`. The default value is for gvim, but it seems nvim-qt needs different arguments. I have no experience with nvim-qt, but I guess you have to add a leading `-- ` (thats dash-dash-space) before the current value of gvimargs.

Comment: @Ralf: Thanks, you are onto something, I modified gvimargs, and it now launches nvim, with no file currently, but that is still progress. I will try to find the correct gvimargs and post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ralf](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/19763/ralf) had the correct intuition regarding the other parameter `gvimargs`.

This does not work with nvim-qt. If you to pass argument from "nvim-qt" to the neovim implementation you have to separate them by a double dash.

This is specific to nvim-qt, nvim in the terminal works both with and without double dash.

I ended up putting in my _vrapperrc

```
set gvimargs=-- +{line} -c "normal zv{col}|" -c "set nobackup" -f -n {file}
```

And it works correctly with NVIM 0.4.2 and Vrapper 0.74.0 on Win10.

For reference, according to the [documentation of vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?topic=configuration), the default value of gvimargs is

```
 gvimargs=+{line} -c normal zv{col}| -c set nobackup -f -n {file}
```

Comment: Have you tried `gvimargs=-- +{line} -c normal zv{col}| -c set nobackup -f -n {file}`? See [here](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/125) or [here](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/wiki#passing-command-line-arguments-to-neovimexe).

Comment: Corrected quoting: Try `set gvimargs=-- +{line} -c "normal zv{col}|" -c "set nobackup" -f -n {file}`

Comment: This works as well, and additionally preserve the column, I will update my answer.